# Using Hyperparameter resulted in lower accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have used Hyperparameter using GridSearchCV and returned back changed alpha value, but it had resulted in lower accuracy

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param_grid = {'alpha':np.arange(1,10) / 10}
ridge_cv = GridSearchCV(ridge,param_grid,cv=5)
ridge_cv.fit(X,y)
print("Tuned Logistic Regression Parameters: {}".format(ridge_cv.best_params_))
print("Best score is {}".format(ridge_cv.best_score_))
```

Output:

```
Tuned Logistic Regression Parameters: {'alpha': 0.1}
Best score is 0.6913858638355904
```

Then I returned back and put it into my Ridge Regression.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
ridge = Ridge(alpha=0.1,normalize=True)
ridge.fit(rescaledX_train,y_train)
y_pred_r = ridge.predict(rescaledX_test)
print('MSE for Ridge: {}'.format(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred_r)))
#  4.771925701539793 - previous score,before using hyperparam
```

Output:

```
MSE for Ridge: 5.81212747265781
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Your `GridSearchCV` is fitting over sets different than `rescaledX_train,y_train`, yes?  If you want to search for just `alpha`, maybe [sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html) is what you want?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I thought that I should use X,y in GridSearchCv

Comment: If the data being scored are different, you expect a different score, yes?